# Angular - formatting an input date and time with or without angular material

Tags: json, angular, input, angular-material

I am part of a team working on an Angular project that involves sending emails to customers or contacts. We have an application that will send out the emails. The user will select an email template from the UI, the application will grab the template from Contentstack (not relevant), the user will fill out an Angular Material-generated form, and the template will be filled with the information from the form.

My current part of the project is putting together the JSON files that will be loaded into Contentstack. I do need to make sure, however, that the templates will prefill correctly before they go out. Part of this involves some small adjustments to the Angular component template. For testing this, I run the Spring Boot (not relevant) portion of the app on my local and then run the Angular portion on my local. The Angular portion pulls in the JSON file I created to use it for the template. Connecting the app to Contentstack comes later.

My concern is about one particular template called Appointment Reminder. I'm having trouble with showing the date and time properly in the populated email template.

Here is the JSON file I am using:

```json
{
  "controls": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
      "label": "First name",
      "value": "",
      "path": "customer.firstName",
      "type": "text",
          "validators": {
          "required": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "lastName",
      "label": "Last name",
      "value": "",
      "path": "customer.lastName",
      "type": "text",
      "validators": {
          "required": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "appointmentDate",
      "label": "Appointment date",
      "value": "",
      "path": "",
      "type": "date",
      "validators": {
          "required": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "appointmentTime",
      "label": "Appointment time",
      "value": "",
      "path": "",
      "type": "time",
      "validators": {
          "required": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "emailTemplate": "Dear ${firstName}, <p></p> <p></p> Your appointment is ${appointmentDate} at ${appointmentTime} to discuss the information I sent you. Please call me 24 hours prior to your phone appointment if you are unable to keep it.",
  "exactTargetMapping": {
    "FirstName": "firstName",
    "LastName": "lastName",
    "State": "state",
    "AgentPhone": "agentPhone",
    "AgentEmail": "agentEmail",
    "AgentName": "agentName",
    "AppointmentDate": "appointmentDate",
    "AppointmentTime": "appointmentTime",
    "CA_LicenseNumber": "caLicenseNumber"
  },
  "messageMetdata": {
    "firstName": "path:control.firstName",
    "lastName": "path:control.lastName",
    "state": "path:customer.state",
    "agentPhone": "path:agent.agentPhone",
    "agentEmail": "path:agent.agentEmail",
    "agentName": "path:agent.agentName",
    "appointmentDate": "path:control.appointmentDate",
    "appointmentTime": "path:control.appointmentTime",
    "caLicenseNumber": "path:agent.caLicenseNumber"
  }
}
```

Here is the Angular HTML that displays the form:

```html
<ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngFor="let control of jsonFormData?.controls" class="example-full-width">

    <!-- input type text-->
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="[
            'text',
            'password',
            'email',
            'number',
            'search',
            'tel',
            'url'
        ].includes(control.type)" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>{{control.label}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput [id]="control.name" [formControlName]="control.name" [type]="control.type" (change)="onChange()">
    </mat-form-field>

     <!-- input type textarea -->
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="[
            'textarea'
            ].includes(control.type)" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>{{control.label}}</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput [id]="control.name" [formControlName]="control.name" (change)="onChange()"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- checkbox-->
    <p *ngIf="[
            'checkbox'
            ].includes(control.type)" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-checkbox [id]="control.name" [formControlName]="control.name" (change)="onChange()">{{control.label}}</mat-checkbox>
    </p>

    <!-- date -->
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="[
        'date'
        ].includes(control.type)" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>{{control.label}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="date" [id]="control.name" [formControlName]="control.name" (change)="onChange()">
        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- date time -->
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="[
        'time'
        ].includes(control.type)" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>{{control.label}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="time" [id]="control.name" [formControlName]="control.name" (change)="onChange()">
        <mat-hint>HH:MM AM/PM</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>

</ng-container>
<!-- <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="submit-button" type="submit">Send</button> -->
```

Here is the Typescript file:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContentStackService } from 'src/app/services/content-stack.service';
import { JsonFormControls, JsonFormData } from '../ssp-send-additional-email/ssp-send-additional-email.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ssp-send-additional-email-template-detail',
  templateUrl: './ssp-send-additional-email-template-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ssp-send-additional-email-template-detail.component.scss'],
})
export class SspSendAdditionalEmailTemplateDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() selectedTemplateId:string;
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup
  @Output() onTemplateDetailedFilled = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() emailTemplateEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();
  public jsonFormData!: JsonFormData;
  public emailTemplate: string
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private contentStackService: ContentStackService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
      .get<JsonFormData>(`/assets/${this.selectedTemplateId}.json`)
      .subscribe((formData: JsonFormData) => {
        this.jsonFormData = formData;
        this.createForm(this.jsonFormData.controls);
        this.emailTemplate = this.jsonFormData.emailTemplate;
        this.emailTemplateEmitter.emit(this.emailTemplate);
      });
  }

  createForm(controls: JsonFormControls[]) {
    for (const control of controls) {
      const validatorsToAdd = [];
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(control.validators)) 
 {
        switch (key) {
          case 'min':
            validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.min(value));
            break;
          case 'max':
            validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.max(value));
            break;
          case 'required':
            if (value) {
              validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.required);
            }
            break;
          case 'requiredTrue':
            if (value) {
              validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.requiredTrue);
            }
            break;
          case 'email':
            if (value) {
              validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.email);
            }
            break;
          case 'minLength':
            validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.minLength(value));
            break;
          case 'maxLength':
            validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.maxLength(value));
            break;
          case 'pattern':
            validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.pattern(value));
            break;
          case 'nullValidator':
            if (value) {
              validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.nullValidator);
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }

      if (control.type === 'date') {
        this.formGroup.addControl(
          control.name,
          this.fb.control(new Date(), validatorsToAdd),
        );
      } else {
        this.formGroup.addControl(
          control.name,
          this.fb.control(control.value, validatorsToAdd),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  onChange() {
    if (this.formGroup.valid) {
      this.onTemplateDetailedFilled.emit(true);
    } else {
      this.onTemplateDetailedFilled.emit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

When the Appointment Reminder template is selected, a form appears to get the information needed to prefill the email template. The input field for the date makes you enter information in the following format: `mm/dd/yyyy`. The input field for the time makes you enter information in the following format: `--:-- --`. That part is fine. The problem is how those present in the email preview. I put in the following on the form:

```txt
First name: Bobby 
Last name Bones 
Appointment date: 05/03/2023 
Appointment time: 01:53 PM
```

This is how the email preview appeared after this:

```html
Dear Bobby, <p></p> <p></p> Your appointment is 2023-05-03 at 13:53 to discuss the information I sent you. Please call me 24 hours prior to your phone appointment if you are unable to keep it.
```

I would like to display the date as May 5, 2023 and the time as 1:53 pm, but I am not sure where to make a change. The Angular HTML for the email preview is just:

```html
{{ emailTemplate }}
```

I did try one possible solution. I changed the input type of the appointment time to "text" and then added a regex pattern in the JSON file. When I put in the time correctly, it appeared correctly in the email preview. The problem was that the `--:-- --` didn't appear and that a user could type anything they wanted. They would get an error of course and couldn't proceed, but I don't think it's acceptable that they could type in a bunch of nonsense like `llaidfoi` in the first place.

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

First something unrelated:

In your template you are doing `*ngIf="['textarea'].includes(control.type)"` which is very strange.  You create an array with a single string just to see if a string is included in your array with a single item.  Just compare it directly like this: `*ngIf="control.type === 'textarea'"`

---

Now regarding your time/date formatting, just combine the date and time to make a JS `Date` object. Once you have a `Date` object, you should pass that around and save that instead of the date and time as plain strings.

**Ideally** in Angular you'll want to use the [formatting date pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) like this:

```html
First name: {{firstName}}
Last name: {{lastName}}
Appointment date: {{dateObj | date:'shortDate'}} 
Appointment time: {{dateObj | date:'shortTime'}}
```

However I see you probably need to keep them as string since you are passing them to some kind of templating system.  So really you could just manually parse the data back out in a few ways:

1.) Use [Angular's `formatDate`](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

```ts
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
import {Component, Inject, LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})
export class ExampleCompoent {
  myDate = formatDate('2023-05-03', 'shortDate' ,this.locale);
  myTime = formatDate('13:53', 'shortTime' ,this.locale);
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string,){}
}
```

2.) Do it manually using JavaScript's `Date` object formatters

```js
const dateStr = '2023-05-03';
const timeStr = '13:53';
const dateObj = new Date(`${dateStr}T${timeStr}`);

console.log("Full Date:",
  dateObj.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
);

console.log("Date Only:",
  dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
);

console.log("Time Only:",
  dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'America/New_York',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
  })
);
```

Comment: I have tried implementing these in my code, but none of the suggestions work.

Comment: When you say they don't work... how do they not work? Are there errors, do the dates not convert, something else?

Comment: The date does not convert.

Comment: Does the above code work? Is so how is it different from your code? Is the data formatted differently?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the TypeScript file. I tried adding the formatting pipe in the JSON template, but the preview then just showed {{appointmentDate | 'shortDate' }} instead of an actual date. Then in the component, in the block that says if (control.type === 'date') , after the new Date() I added the .toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric }). That didn't change anything in the template - it still showed 2023-05-03.

Comment: Well yeah, the formatting pipe is an Angular feature, JSON just holds data and Angular can't process that. I was just giving you examples of ways that Angular handles dates. That's why I said "ideally" at the top and then mentioned the other two ways to do it since you are using string templates. The TS file you added above is what handles the UI for where you input the dates? You need to format the date **for display**, which means somewhere between when the date is selected and where it gets filled in on the template. I'm not clear on where that is processed in your code.